# Jquery plus and minus button toggle

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

I am a bit of an amateur so I don't know how to achieve this goal.
I would have some buttons that need to toggle plus or minus:

http://jsfiddle.net/tonylka10/0eq456w9/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.expandable').click(function () {
    $('.expandable').not(this).nextAll('tr').hide();
    $(this).nextAll('tr').toggle(350);

});
$('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function () {
    if (!($(this).is('.expandable'))) $(this).hide();
});
});
```

How can I achieve this with the code that I already have?

I would like to have the same functionality as the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/1/

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Example doesn't work for me if you click directly on the '+' FYI.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I hadn't noticed that before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/0eq456w9/10/

```
$('.expandable').click(function () {
    $('.expandable').not(this).nextAll('tr').hide();
    $('.expandable').not(this).find('input[type="button"]').val("+");
    $(this).nextAll('tr').toggle(350);
    if( $(this).find('input[type="button"]').val() == "+")
    {
        $(this).find('input[type="button"]').val("-");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('input[type="button"]').val("+");
    }

});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! I am going to test this. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for a working solution even though there are cleaner ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to the event handler:

```
    $(this).find('[id^=myButton]').val(function(i,v) { 
        return v.trim() == '+' ? '-' : '+';
    });
    $('.expandable').not(this).find('input[type="button"]').val("+");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0eq456w9/11/)

Comment: That works but the only problem I have with that is that when the row closes, the button stays a minus symbol. I would like for the value to be plus again.

Comment: What browser are you testing with? Works fine on latest Google Chrome. @tonylka10?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am on firefox, I will keep testing. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For me the demo works right. Try it again @tonylka10

Comment: This line is missing : $('.expandable').not(this).find('input[type="button"]').val("+"); He want a + on any other button not clicked since everything is collaspe when you click an other row.

Comment: @mathiulabrieparent I do see your point. Code and demo is updated.

Comment: Click on the first Hall Directors. The first one is showed. Click the second one, the first one is collapse the second one is showed, however the first button remain '-' without the add on.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the span in the h3 or add the span in click event target.
http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/238/

```
<ul id="toggle-view">
    <li>
        <h3>Title 1<span>+</span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Title 2<span>+</span></h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Title 3<span>+</span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping in your js

```
$('li h3, li span', parent).click(function()
```

for

```
$('li h3', parent).click(function()
```

Then you can put different images in the spans, try using bootstrap they have some pretty nice glpyhicons [bs components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Give this a look it is using bootstrap for you images. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/241/)